# Tomcat to refuse connections after certain amount of requests

Tags: java, http, tomcat7, tcp

I am using Tomcat 7.0.32, with Java 1.7. I have a use case where my client is single threaded and sends request at a high pace. Now my problem is my server, processes all requests, this it does at the expense of high latency. This is quite obvious since the communication is not concurrent.
I know if my connector is BIO and i set max threads to 1, my accept count as 1, then if i send 3 concurrent request, it fails with Connection Refused. Which is expected.

However, if the client is single threaded, then the above does not apply, i can continue to send as many requests as i want. However the latency drops. This again is natural. Now i am trying to check if at all there are any server(i.e. Tomcat) configuration available which can influence the OS to refuse connections if the time to acquire connections is high.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Vicky

Comment: The question is unclear. The title says `refuse connections after certain amount of requests` and you are asking this `refuse connections if the time to acquire connections is high.`. It appears you are asking about connection or read timeouts.

Comment: "Now my problem is my server, processes all requests, this it does at the expense of high latency." Please explain.

Comment: @Bala - Point is i want tomcat to influence OS, so that if the time to acquire connections is getting high just refuse it. But i doubt there is such a config.

Comment: @EJP As explained, max threads indicated how much concurrency tomcat can support, so maxthreads=1 + acceptcnt=1, equals concurrency supported = 2, and if my client starts pushing data with 3 concurrent threads, i get Client refused after 3 connections itself. Now i want to achieve a similar thing with a single client(no concurrency). Hope that clears it out.

Answer (score -2):

> This is quite obvious since the communication is not concurrent.

It's not obvious to me. I run a dozen highly concurrent Tomcats.

If you are suggesting that Tomcat is not a highly concurrent server you are mistaken. It is. You need to reexamine your observations and your assumptions.

Comment: This is not a answer but a comment!

Comment: @harsh Debatable. If the question is based on a misconception or *non sequitur* the only possible answer is to say so.

Comment: @EJP - You are missing the point here. I know and hence i stated with concurrent requests i can achieve the feat based on the configurations i add to tomcat i.e. Max threads and Accept Count. So there is no doubt that tomcat cannot handle concurrency. Just that i am looking to achieve something similar with single client (no concurrency).